# Polymer 1.x: Pre-loading element attributes

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to load my element with a predefined value for the `selected` attribute of `['Colorado', 'South Dakota']`.

I expect to see the page load a map with an outline of all the U.S. states. With no errors in the console. And the states of Colorado and South Dakota pre-selected and colored blue.

Instead, I see a blank page (no map at all) and a set of errors in the console beginning with the following:

console.error

> `Polymer::Attributes: couldn't decode Array as JSON`

The following steps will recreate the problem:

1. [Open this jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qupoleveja/1/edit?html,console,output).
2. Notice the map loads properly in the output pane. (And works properly when states are selected and de-selected.)
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page to the `<x-element>` tag.
4. Delete the `x` character in front of the `selected` attribute so the complete attribute reads: `selected="['Colorado', 'South Dakota']"`.
5. Notice the map disappeared, no longer loads properly and the errors described above appear in the console.
6. Replace the `x` you just deleted and notice the map loads and works properly again.

### Question

What could be going on here? What is causing the problem and what can fix it? Please include a working jsBin example of your solution if you can.

http://jsbin.com/qupoleveja/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
  <link href="google-chart/google-chart.html" rel="import">
</head>

<body>

  <dom-module id="x-element">

    <template>
      <style>
        google-chart {
          width: 100%;
          max-height: 300px;
        }
      </style>
      <button on-tap="_show">Show</button>
      <div>[[selected]]</div>
      <google-chart
        id="geochart"
        type="geo"
        options="{{options}}"
        data="{{items}}"
        xon-google-chart-select="_onGoogleChartSelect"></google-chart>
    </template>

    <script>
      (function(){
        Polymer({
          is: 'x-element',
          /** /
           * Fired when user selects chart item.
           *
           * @event us-map-select
           * @param {object} detail Alpabetized array of selected state names.
          /**/
          properties: {
            selected: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true,
              //reflectToAttribute: true,
            },
            items: {
              type: Array,
              notify: true,
              reflectToAttribute: true,
            },
            color: {
              type: String, // '#455A64'
              value: function() {
                return 'blue';
              }
            },
            options: {
              type: Object,
              notify: true,
              reflectToAttribute: true,
              computed: '_computeOptions(color)'
            },
            itemIndices: {
              type: Object,
              computed: '_computeItemIndices(items)',
            },
          },

          observers: [
            '_selectedChanged(selected.*)'
          ],

          ready: function() {
            var a = [['State', 'Select'], ['Alabama', 0], ['Alaska', 0], ['Arizona', 0], ['Arkansas', 0], ['California', 0], ['Colorado', 0], ['Connecticut', 0], ['Delaware', 0], ['Florida', 0], ['Georgia', 0], ['Hawaii', 0], ['Idaho', 0],  ['Illinois', 0], ['Indiana', 0], ['Iowa', 0], ['Kansas', 0], ['Kentucky', 0], ['Louisiana', 0], ['Maine', 0], ['Maryland', 0], ['Massachusetts', 0], ['Michigan', 0], ['Minnesota', 0], ['Mississippi', 0], ['Missouri', 0], ['Montana', 0], ['Nebraska', 0], ['Nevada', 0], ['New Hampshire', 0], ['New Jersey', 0], ['New Mexico', 0], ['New York', 0], ['North Carolina', 0], ['North Dakota', 0], ['Ohio', 0], ['Oklahoma', 0], ['Oregon', 0], ['Pennsylvania', 0], ['Rhode Island', 0], ['South Carolina', 0], ['South Dakota', 0], ['Tennessee', 0], ['Texas', 0], ['Utah', 0], ['Vermont', 0], ['Virginia', 0], ['Washington', 0], ['West Virginia', 0], ['Wisconsin', 0], ['Wyoming', 0]];
            this.set('items', a);
            var _this = this; 
            this.$.geochart.addEventListener('google-chart-select',function(e){this._onGoogleChartSelect(e)}.bind(_this));
          },

          _computeItemIndices: function(a) {
            var out = {},
                i = a.length;
            while(i--){
              out[a[i][0]] = i;
            }
            return out;
          },

          _onGoogleChartSelect: function(e) {
            var str = e.path[0].textContent.split('Select')[0].trim(), // e.g. 'Ohio'
                temp = [],
                ar = this.items,
                index = this.itemIndices[str], // e.g. 35
                i = ar.length;
            this.set('items.' + index + '.1', ar[index][1] ? 0 : 1);
            while(i---1){
              /** /
              if(str === ar[i][0]){
                this.set('items.' + i + '.1', ar[i][1] ? 0 : 1);
                //this.items[i][1] = ar[i][1] ? 0 : 1;
              }
              /**/
              if(ar[i][1]){
                temp.push(ar[i][0]);
              }
            }
            temp.sort();
            this.set('selected', temp);
            this._drawChart();
            //console.log(this.selected);
          },

          _drawChart: function() {
            this.$.geochart._dataTable=this.$.geochart._createDataTable(this.items);
            this.$.geochart._chartObject.draw(this.$.geochart._dataTable,
                                              this.$.geochart.options);
          },

          doAll: function(verb) {
            verb = verb || 'clear'; // verb: 'clear'(default)|'select'
            verb = (verb === 'select') ? 'select' : 'clear';
            this._doAll(verb);
            this._drawChart();
          },

          _doAll: function(verb) {
            var resetSelect = (verb && verb === 'some') ? false : true;
            verb = verb || 'clear'; // verb: 'clear'(default)|'select'|'some'
            verb = (verb === 'select') ? 'select' : 'clear';
            var temp = [],
                items = this.items,
                i = items.length;
            switch(verb) {
              case 'select':
                while(i---1){
                  items[i][1] = 1;
                  temp.push(items[i][0]);
                }
                break;
              case 'clear':
                while(i---1){
                  items[i][1] = 0;
                }
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
            this.set('items', items);
            if(resetSelect){
              temp.sort();
              this.set('selected', temp);
            }
          },

          _selectedChanged: function(ar) {
            var a = ar.base,
                i = a.length;
            this._doAll('some');
            while(i--){
              var index = this.itemIndices[a[i]];
              this.set('items.' + index + '.1', 1);
            }
            this._drawChart();
            this.fire('us-map-select',this.selected)
            console.log(this.selected);
          },

          _computeOptions: function() {
            return {
              region: 'US',
              displayMode: 'regions',
              resolution: 'provinces',
              legend: 'none',
              defaultColor: '#F5F5F5',
              colorAxis: {
                colors: ['#F5F5F5', this.color],
                minValue: 0,  
                maxValue: 1,
              }
            }
          },

          _show: function(){
            //this.set('selected', ['Ohio', 'New Mexico']);
            this.doAll();
            //console.log(this.itemIndices);
          },
        });
      })();
    </script>

  </dom-module>

  <x-element xcolor="#455A64"
             xselected="['Colorado', 'South Dakota']" ></x-element>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
selected='["Colorado", "South Dakota"]'
```

JSON needs double quotes.

Comment: It's weird because I thought I had already tried that, but... the first one seems to work `selected='["Colorado", "South Dakota"]'`. Sort of. There is still an error but it's a new error now. So I think the correct course of action is to accept your answer (since it solved the problem described) and to write a new question for the new problem that has now popped up. I hope no one marks the new question as the same question because it will, in fact, be different. Although very similar. +1